# Storing a large list in isolatedStorage on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm storing a List with around 3,000 objects in Isolatedstorage using Xml serialize.
It takes too long to deserialize this and I was wondering if you have any recommendations to speed it up.

The time is tolerable to deserialize up to 500 objects, but takes forever to deserialize 3000.
Does it take longer just on the emulator and will be faster on the phone?

I did a whole bunch of searching and some article said to use a binary stream reader, but I can't find it. Whether I store in binary or xml doesn't matter, I just want to persist the List.

I don't want to look at asynchronous loading just yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the binary serializer that is a part of sharpSerializer:
http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html

It's very easy and works quite well.

Here's a blog that talks about using it in WP7:
http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-sharpserializer/

I am using it like (consider this psuedocode, and using the functions listed on eugenedotnet)

in App.xaml.cs:

```
Application_Dectivated()
{
     IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
     Serialize(stream,(obj)MyHugeList<myObject>);
}

Application_Activated()
{
     IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open);
     Deserialize(stream,(obj)MyHugeList<myObject>);
}
```

Comment: very useful. I am using the binary mode, and it works well, thx

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, some good info here already, so +1 there.

I would recommend reviewing these articles, giving you some good perspective on what performance you can expect using a variety of out of the box serialisation techniques.

[Windows Phone 7 Serialization: Comparison | eugenedotnet blog](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-comparison/)

[WP7 Serialization Comparison](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison.aspx)

You might also consider using multiple files if you don't need to load and write everything in one hit all the time.

I would reiterate Jeff's advice that it would really be a good idea to get any substantial work you find remaining after this onto a background thread so as not to degrade the user interaction experience.

It's fairly straight forward. Here is a walkthrough I often recommend and people find concise and helpful.

[Phạm Tiểu Giao - Threads in WP7](http://my.opera.com/phamtieugiao/blog/2010/10/10/threads-in-wp7)

And also this, recently by Shawn Wildermuth which looks quite good too.

[Shawn Wildermuth - Architecting WP7 - Part 9 of 10: Threading](http://wildermuth.com/2011/01/11/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_9_of_10_Threading)

Comment: Mick and Jeff, thx for your advice. i didn't really worry about a background thread because the ui anyway needs to wait for the file to load and info to show. That is a workaround and not really speeding up the process imho. Also, i have read Eugene's (nice) article, which was good info. I'll check the other two links.

Comment: The premise of async is that the UI is free to be operated by the user even while there is processing happening that they are waiting on. They might want to press the back key for example. The point is the user should be in control of navigation, not the app. If there are parts of the app that don't make sense to use while this process is happening, then just see to it that they are not enabled until the processing is complete. I dont consider async to be a workaround, but a choice to make an improved experience possible.

Answer (score 3):

For that many items, you need to build your optimized serialization story. I see many people using simple CSV and text formats to do this.

The built-in serializers just aren't going to be fast enough.

You should really consider doing this all on a background thread for a lot of reasons, though yes you have indicated you do not want to do this.